Recently accepted paper: haven't heard from publisher
My paper was accepted by a journal a week ago. The acceptance email told me to expect an email from the publisher asking me to provide the license for publication. So far I haven't received anything. In my experience, I always heard from journal publishers within hours after receiving the acceptance decision. Should I inquire and, if so, should I contact the academic editor or the publisher directly?

First check your junk mail.

Nothing in spam :)

Is your prior experience with the same journal and/or publisher?

I don't think I've published with the same publisher.

Yes, you can enquire and ask if there is any difficulty. But a week is no time at all. The person who handles such things might be away or busy or whatever.
An enquiry is important only if you have some deadlines, but that is unlikely in the case of an accepted paper and the schedule is theirs to make (or break).
